# Explanation on the logic for git log command git log master-1.0.83..HEAD

Tags: javascript, git, commit, git-log, changelog

For this specific library https://github.com/rafinskipg/git-changelog
I enabled its debugging mode and saw the logic that is been used to pull in the Git log, I got lost in some of them.

In the debugging log I saw this:

```
git log --grep="^fix|^feat|^docs|BREAKING|^refactor|^style|^test|^Merge branch|^Merge pull request" -i -E --format=%H%n%s%n%b%n==END== master-1.0.83..HEAD
```

I especially interested to know what `==END== master-1.0.83..HEAD` does? I am still having issue understanding, that, how the log of changes got pulled in? Is it base on comparing parent branch that current branch branched off from? or it is base on the branch that I fill in .changelogrc, for example, in this case, I added a new param `"tag": "master-1.0.83"`, I feel this `==END==master-1.0.83..HEAD` is the factor that determines how the branches are compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a space in your view.

```
--format=%H%n%s%n%b%n==END== master-1.0.83..HEAD
```

is

```
--format=%H%n%s%n%b%n==END==
master-1.0.83..HEAD
```

The `==END==` is part of the `--format` and is probably a marker for the consumer of the log where stops parsing one commit.

`master-1.0.83..HEAD` means compare `master-1.0.83` against `HEAD` where `HEAD` is the currently checked out commit.

Comment: yea I think that extra space missing is because how the lib print out the log in the console. thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, the space is there in the debug log output you pasted. It is just missing in the text you wrote thereafter.

Comment: Only one occation. ;-)